# gatsbyjs - How to get Contentful posts filtered by year?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, contentful, gatsby

I'm using `gatsby-source-contentful` where I have a type called `ContentfulBlogPost`, whose schema looks something like this:

```
{
  id
  title
  body
  date
}
```

Date is a string (in `YYYY-MM-DD` format), auto-magically handled by Gatsby's data layer as a Moment object; I can call `fromNow` and `formatString` on it and all that.

What I want is to use GraphQL to query for a list of posts from a given year, based on that date field.

If I do this:

```
{
   allContentfulBlogPost(
     filter: { date: { regex: "/^2017/" } }
   ) {
     ...
   }
}
```

then I get this error: `"Cannot read property 'fromNow' of undefined"`

What I *really* want is to be able to filter the `allContentfulBlogPost` data set by date, either by transforming the date into an integer/string year and finding on that, or by asking for all items whose date falls between Jan 1 and Dec 31 of the given year.

Right now, I have a query running in `gatsby-node` that pulls in *all* blog posts, then groups them by year in JS and then passes the array of posts into a template. This works, but it really seems like there should be a GraphQL way of doing this?

Comment: This looks like a bug on Gatsby side.